# Como realizar una forma rectangular que se autoajuste a la pantalla de WPF en Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando realizar un rectángulo que se auto ajuste a la pantalla de WPF y además que consiga cambiar de color cuando es atravesada por una mano del programa de body tracking de Kinect, pero de momento no consigo ninguna de las dos cosas, alguien puede echarme una mano por favor. En internet no hay ningún ejemplo de realmente lo que me gustaría conseguir o al menos yo no lo he encontrado. Un Saludo
Creo que el la parte de código a implementar iría aquí:

```
if (dataReceived)
{
        using (DrawingContext dc = this.drawingGroup.Open())
        {

            // Draw a transparent background to set the render size: Se trata de realizar un fondo , en este caso negro
            dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, this.displayWidth, this.displayHeight));

            int penIndex = 0;
            foreach (Body body in this.bodies)
            {
                Pen drawPen = this.bodyColors[penIndex++];

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Que problema tienes con tu código? En cuanto al tamaño del rectángulo, intenta utilizar `SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight` y
 `SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth`

Comment: que el fondo no lo quiero modificar, simplemente quiero implementar un rectángulo en WPF Adicional para que sirva como referencia al pasar la mano supuestamente por un sitio donde estará esa barra(rectángulo) y claro esa barra no se modifica cuando quiero agrandar la ventana de aplicación en tiempo de ejecución, esa barra por asi decirlo es independiente